How to prevent constant third-party round trip requests with OAuth?
We are currently using a third-party authentication provider implementing the OAuth2.0 protocol.
Essentially, the workflow is that the User is re-directed to the third-party site, where they sign in and are issued an access token. Then, WHILE TRUE: When a user requests a resource from our server, the user provides this access token to us as a Bearer [my_token] in the Authorization header field.  We get this token on the backend and then need to identify/authenticate the user.  In order to identify/authenticate the user based on this token, we make a request to the third-party with this token.  The response contains information that identifies the user (a username).  We then use that username to service the request and send a response back to the user.
This workflow is unfortunate, because it doubles the latency for every request that a user makes to our service.  I.e. each request not only requires the round-trip time to our servers, but requires an intermediate round-trip request to the third-party from our servers before we can begin servicing the request.
What is a safe and performant way to prevent constant third-party round trip requests when using OAuth for authentication?

A very typical way to solve this is to cache the response you got with a low expiry time in for example Redis or a database.
This is a fairly low-tech solution, and easy to do. The main risk is that the access token could have expired before your cache is, but if you keep the cache timeout relatively low (like a few minutes) this risk is relatively low.

Is this a security risk for the user in some way?  I.e. if our DB were compromised, then an attacker could use these access tokens on other sites that employ the same third-party auth service?

An easy solution to this would be to hash the incoming access tokens.

When using OAuth 2.0 for authentication you must revert to the OpenID Connect profile for security reasons, see: https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/ The OIDC client should persist and reuse the same access token for multiple resource requests, and possibly - i.e. when dealing with a Web Client - create a session for the user, e.g. by storing server side state tracked by a session cookie.

Our third-party provider supports OpenID Connect.  Our site is currently storing the access token in the user's browser, and sending that to our servers (the client) with each request.  Is the user's browser not supposed to be storing the access token, but we should be storing it server-side?

One common solution is to issue your own authentication token, and have that be the bearer token that is sent with all API requests.
You would implement a /login or /tokenExchange endpoint that accepts the bearer token issued by the OAuth identity provider, validates it with the IdP, then exchanges it for a local token -- or better a pair of access and refresh tokens.
Depending on your security needs, the local tokens could either be longer-lived (hours, days, or even weeks), or tied to the duration of the IdP token.
The flow from a client (say a front-end website that uses your API) looks something like:
client: thirdPartyProvider.login() --> identityToken
client: api.exchange(identityToken):
    api: thirdPartyProvider.validate(identityToken)
    api: generateAccessToken() --> [accessToken, refreshToken]
    --> return tokens
...
client: api.getSomeData(Headers=bearer accessToken) --> success (data)
...
client: api.getSomeData(Headers=bearer accessToken) --> fail (token expired)
client: api.refreshToken(refreshToken)
    api.thirdPartyProvider.isUSerStillValid()
    api.generateAccessToken(refreshToken)
    ---> new access token

One consideration is how critical it is for your API to immediately no longer authorize a user if/when they become invalid with their IdP. If you need that to be immediate, you either have to do a round-trip to the IdP for every API request (called introspection in the OAuth framework), or you need to subscribe to the IdP's feed in invalidation actions (which requires you to keep state about what access tokens have been issued).
But if you can accept that there will be a period of time (length determined by the expiration of the access and refresh tokens) between when a user is no longer valid with their IdP and when they can no longer authenticate with your API, then using a token exchange flow token lowers the round-trip time to just infrequent refresh()/login() requests.
 
Example
An example policy that uses Google as the IdP might be:

Google identity token duration: 1 hour (not changeable)
API access token duration: 10 minutes
API refresh token duration: 3 days
API state: list of blacklisted refresh tokens

A user would authenticate with Google once, then exchange Google's identity token for an API access/refresh pair. The access token would need to be sent with every API request. On each request, the API would check both expiration of the token. On refresh requests, it would also check that the refresh token had not been blacklisted
If the token was expired, the client would send the refresh token and get a new access token.
In this setup:

The user changes their password with Google and/or logs out of all accounts. They would not unauthenticated with your API until the refresh token expired (up to 3 days)
The user is deactivated in your system by blacklisting their refresh token. The user could still make authenticated requests for up to 10 minutes, until their current access token expired.

